# Recover deleted Windows volumes

Tags: windows, forensics, data-recovery

I have been given an HDD image. I believe the image was taken with dd. I have ingested the file using Autopsy and can see there are 4 volumes, like so

- Volume 1 - Unallocated. I believe NOT securely deleted
- Volume 2 - NTFS / exFAT. Windows Vista, not deleted
- Volume 3 - DOS FAT 12. Not deleted.
- Volume 4 - Unallocated

**I would like to know how (if possible), to recover Volume 1 so that I can mount the image in a Virtual Machine. I would also like to recover Volume 4.**

Note: I have access to Windows and Linux to perform this analysis.

Comment: There is a difference between mounting it and booting it. Do you really want to boot from this volume, or just mount it to see/recover data?

Comment: Good point. Ultimately I need to read the data, so mounting would suffice. I would like to boot as well but would settle for you just mounting.

Comment: There are plenty of recovery options / methods. What did you attempt so far ?